# Get "From" and "To" addresses with Gmail API

Tags: php, email, gmail, gmail-api

I use Gmail API for retrieving messages from Gmail account and storing them in my DB. I want to store To/From email addresses for each message.

Each message contains headers array and within this array there are two fields like "From" and "To". However they also contain contact name, not a pure email address.

So right now I parse them like this:

```
if ($header->name === 'From') {
    preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $header->value, $matches);
    $from = $matches[0][0];
}
```

But is this the only way to get to/from adresses? Only by manually parsing headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [User.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) only includes from/to in standard RFC 2822 headers.

You should avoid using regex to parse email addresses though. They are complex and can contain almost any character. See this [regex for an example](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) of what a compliant version would look like.

Comment: Thanks, but how else can I retrieve the email address?

Comment: I would suggest working to strip away any parts you know not to be part of an email address. E.g. `First Last <name@example.com>` could be parsed based on `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

I use [imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist)

It works like this:

```
$arrayOfAddressesFoundInString = imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist('Some Name <someemail@test.com>', 'localhost');
```

I created small function which does the job for me:

```
function getAddressFromString($address_string) {
            $address_array  = imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist($address_string, "localhost");
            if (!is_array($address_array) || count($address_array) < 1) 
                return FALSE;
            return $address_array[0]->mailbox . '@' . $address_array[0]->host;
        }
```

Comment: Interesting to know about this function. Though it's not better than regexp.